# Android TabLayout how to make two underlines

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

I'm trying to create `TabLayout` and it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrXDy.jpg).

And i want to make one more under line [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46lGJ.jpg).

Here is my own yellow line and i want to make the black one, and when i change tabs yellow line change itself position. Maybe i need to do some background line, but i dont understand how to

XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    style="@style/AppTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />

<style name="AppTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/visit_tabs_indicator</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">4dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingStart">6dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingEnd">6dp</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/AppTabTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/visit_tabs_text</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create background drawable which having bottom black line.
i.e `tab_ract_border.xml`

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="-2dp" android:right="-2dp" android:left="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

then apply this drawable to background of `Tablayout`
i.e `app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_ract_border"`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_main_tab_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#F3CD84"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_ract_border"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
    app:tabTextColor="#000000" />
```

njoe it will work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

In you `style.xml` code:

```
<style name="AppTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/visit_tabs_indicator</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">4dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingStart">6dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingEnd">6dp</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/myTabBackground</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/AppTabTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/visit_tabs_text</item>
</style>
```

Then create new xml resource file under Drawable folder: `myTabBackground.xml`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@android:color/white"
        android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>
</selector>
```

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: its not i've asked, but thanks for solution - it s good for my practise!